# Value of $f(2016),$ If $f(x) = f(2x)\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ are given

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

> If $f(x) = f(2x)\forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(5) = 10,$ Then $f(2016) = $

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $0<x<1$

Then $f(x)=f(2x) = f(2^2x) = f(2^3x)=......=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(2^nx) = f(0)=\bf{Constant}$

and when $x>1$

Then $\displaystyle f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = f\left(\frac{x}{2^2}\right)=f\left(\frac{x}{2^3}\right)=.......=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}=f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=f(0)=\bf{Constant}$

But I did not understand How can we solve for $x<0$ and $x=0$ and for $x=1$

Help Required, Thanks

Comment: actually $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: For $0 < x < 1$, how is $\lim_{n \to 0}f(2^nx) = f(0)$? For $0 < x < 1$, as $n \to \infty$, $2^nx \to \infty$ not $0$.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, Would you like to explain me how can i solve above question.

Comment: Isn't your second  thing good enough? You don't even need $x>1$

Comment: Thanks  Zachary Selk Got it.

Comment: f(x) is a constant function maybe.

Comment: Use f is continous.  If f (c) ne f (1) let e = |f (c) - f (1)|.  For any d > 0 there exit 1/2^m < d so |1/2^m+1 - c/2^m+1|<d but |f (1/2^m+1)- f (c/2^m+1)| = |f (1)-f (c)| = e so f is not continuous at c.  A contradiction.  So all f (x) = f (1) and f is constant.  So f (2016)=f (5)=10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any real number $x$, and any non-negative integer $n$, you have:

$f(x) = f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) = f\left(\dfrac{x}{4}\right) = \cdots f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)$.  Hence, $f(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)$.

But, since $f(x)$ is continuous, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = f(0)$.

Therefore, $f(x) = f(0) = \textbf{constant}$ for all real numbers $x$.

Since we are also given that $f(5) = 10$, we get $\textbf{constant} = 10$. Therefore, $f(2016) = 10$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your proof has already made sense.

$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=...=f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right),$$

let $$n\rightarrow\infty,f(x)=f(0)$$

So $f(2016)=10.$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/bizarre-ways-of-using-tex Please see this to understand how to use Tex better. In particular, Tex your entire equation.

Answer (score 2):

f is continuous.  For any $\epsilon >0$, we can find $\delta$ so that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f (x)-f (y)| < \epsilon$.

For any delta I can find an $m $ so that $2016/2^m - 5/2^m =(2011)/2^m <\delta $.

So $|f (2016/2^m) - f (5/2^m)| < \epsilon $.  By induction $f (x/2^m)=f (x) $ so $|f (2016) - f (5)| < \epsilon $.

But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and so $f (2016)=f (5)=10$.